# Create Anchor with ID from Array - Codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, anchor, codeigniter-3

I need to create an anchor tag with title Name [AC NAGAR] and ID with a number [1].

How is it possible?

```
Array ( [1] => AC NAGAR [2] => ADDANKI [3] => Addanki 2);
```

Comment: `foreach($array as $k => $v){ echo "<a title='$v' id='$k' href='$k'>$v </a>" };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $input = array("a" => "green", "red", "b" => "green", "blue", "red");
  foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
    # code...
    echo $value;
  }
```

You can add a anchor tag in the foreach depends upon your functionality
like

```
   echo "<a href='#'>$value</a>";
```

This will help for you.

Comment: how to use anchor function?